# How to remove the merged rows in excel using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file where some of the rows are merged. Please find the snippet of the file below.

[image]

And I want my file to look like the this:

[image].

As you can see `First String` and `Second String` are irrelevant to my data and I want to drop that row.

Here is my trial.

```
rule1 = lambda x: x not in ['']
u = excel_file.loc[excel_file['Date1'].apply(rule1) & excel_file['Date2'].apply(rule1) & excel_file['ID'].apply(rule1) & excel_file['Supervisor'].apply(rule1)].index


excel_file.iloc[u,:]
```

Where `excel_file` is the excel file I have imported to the python environment.

And this gives me the following output.

```
    Date1       Date2       ID  Supervisor
0   2019-12-05  2019-12-05  5865    Jack
1   15/06/2019  15/06/2019  5869    Michel
3   2020-12-05  2020-12-05  5867    Helen
4   20/6/2020   20/6/2020   5867    Amanda
```

This is working perfectly, but I am wondering if there is any other alternative or efficient way to solve this because if for instance `Supervisor` is empty, my code will remove that row just because one of the columns is empty.

Comment: this is just a shot in the dark : ```df.loc[df.ne('First String').all(axis=1)]``` Assumption is that first and second string are on the same row. lemme know if it falls thru.

Comment: Yes, this works as well, but I am going to have to mention `First String` all the time, and what if it is this string is different from `First String` next time?

Comment: hmmm... ok, what if we run ```pd.to_datetime(df, errors,='coerce')```. it should give u ```NaT``` for the string entries, and u can filter them out... shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it with types check,

```py
for row in rows:
  if not row[2].isdigit():
    remove_row()
```

something like that, to be more generic

Comment: I am getting the this error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: If the row is Array you need to change it to row[2]